Scraping multiple sites with different structures
I would like to scrape over 193 websites based particular parameters specifically related to common features of the sites e.g. AI chat bot and after retrieving this data, I would like to consolidate the same to be the training dataset for a ML model. My challenge is what tool can I use to get accurate results from scraping considering the different structures of this websites and how can I automate the data flow from scraping to the ML model?
